# How to copy over common base properties using linq

Tags: c#, linq, oop

I have 2 different child classes. The main reason is cos the database fields are different from the one going into the Gui. So they both have common parent class.

```
Class DbChild1 : Parent1
{ ....
}

Class GuiChild1 : Parent1
{....
}
```

I have a IEnumerable resultset of the DbChild1.  I am trying to use Linq to copy the data over. But since there are really lots of properties and I am doing this in more than one place for other similar DBclass and Gui class, I am wondering if there is any shortcut way to copy over the common parent properties instead of copying one by one.

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Why would you need to do that if both types inherit from `Parent1` ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)?

Comment: @user3185569 mainly cos they have other properties in them too common parent.

Comment: try using some Mapping package like @AdilMammadov suggested, or even try to serialize the source and desterilize to the target using  Json.Net.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't checked AutoMapper you can try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbChild1ResultSet = new[]
        {
            new DbChild1()
            {
                Field1 = "1",
                Field2 = "2",
                DbChild1Field1 = "3"
            },
            new DbChild1()
            {
                Field1 = "11",
                Field2 = "22",
                DbChild1Field1 = "33"
            },
        };

        var guiChild1ResultSet = dbChild1ResultSet.Select(x => new GuiChild1(x)
        {
            GuiChild1Field1 = x.DbChild1Field1
        });
    }
}

public class Parent1
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    public Parent1()
    {

    }

    public Parent1(Parent1 toCopyFrom)
    {
        Field1 = toCopyFrom.Field1;
        Field2 = toCopyFrom.Field2;
    }
}

public class DbChild1 : Parent1
{
    public string DbChild1Field1 { get; set; }

    public DbChild1()
    {

    }

    public DbChild1(Parent1 toCopyFrom) : base(toCopyFrom)
    {
    }
}

public class GuiChild1 : Parent1
{
    public string GuiChild1Field1 { get; set; }

    public GuiChild1()
    {

    }

    public GuiChild1(Parent1 toCopyFrom) : base(toCopyFrom)
    {
    }
}
```